# How to assign a recipient to .To?

Tags: vba, outlook

I convert a worksheet into a PDF and am trying to have that PDF emailed to me and copied to another person. All of this will be assigned to an action button/trigger.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendExcelFileAsPDF()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim emItem As Object
Dim Receipt As String, Subject As String
Dim Message As String, Fname As String

Dim Recipient As Outlook.Recipient
Recipient = "xxxxx.xxxxx@fedex.com"
Subject = "Weekly Critical Items" & " " & Range("L1")
Message = Range("D2") & Range("J2") & "Weekly Critical Items submitted" & 
Range("L1") & " " & "in PDF Format"
Message = Message & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Offload Ops"
Fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Fname

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

Set emItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With emItem
    .To = Recipient = "xxxxx.xxxxx@fedex.com"
    .Subject = Subject
    .Body = Message
    .Attachements.Add Fname
    .Send
End With
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The recipient line is where I am having issues. When I run the debugger, it's giving

> Run-Time error '91: Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: That's a [recipient object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients), I think you might need to move that to after `emItem` is set, and use instead `emItem.Recipients.Add ("dennis...")`?

Comment: I think this line should just be .To = Recipient , you don't have to write ="".

Comment: Can you clarify which line is causing the issue? I didn't notice the last one @ImranMalek points out, which would error as well. (Not sure if the one I mean is causing your error...)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! The line:
Recipient = "dennis.aikens@fedex.com"

is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dim recipient as string and update the .to assignment:

Change

```
Dim Recipient As Outlook.Recipient

.To = Recipient = "dennis.aikens@fedex.com"
```

to

```
Dim Recipient As string

.To = Recipient
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

.To = Recipient = "dennis.aikens@fedex.com"

Should be just

.To = Recipient